# Vuforia Cloud Recognition Android Application

Tags: android, vuforia

I am trying to use vuforia framework (https://developer.vuforia.com/library/all-articles) to do a simple image recognition task via cloud. My question is that is it possible to take an image from camera and search it in vuforia cloud (without realtime frame processing - AR) ? They have very limited documentation and could not find any relevant information regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuforia now allows us to upload objects into the target manager, whether it is an image or cylinder/box, or even a multiple dimension object.

Upload these into Vuforia Database (Database should be for cloud reco. If not, create a new database for it) and get the Client Keys.

Now you can import the Cloud reco prefab and add a text on top to augment.

Hope this helped. :)

Comment: sorry that video is pivate it says

Comment: @firativerson this was answered more than a year back. I'll edit the answer without the link, it still answers the question, though.